# Any tool to allow moving of elements on a webpage to aid design?

Tags: css, firefox-addon

Are there any tools/Firefox plugins that will allow you to drag elements (divs, images etc) about on the page, and tell you the amount (x, y) that you have moved it?
It would speed up designing a page a lot, instead of tweak css, reload page, tweak css, reload page.

I've found the [Firefox Web Developer extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/) useful for editing the css live, but it seems to hide background images when used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I use related to your question:

- [**MeasureIt**](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/539) Firefox extension to measure pixels on viewport
- **Firebug** 1.5 and its HTML / right-handed half / **Appearance**. It's useful as is AND it's editable. 
  Obviously, I also use a lot the Style pane. Click on the left of an instruction to disable it temporarily; right-click to add inline CSS for this element selected in the HTML on the left-hand half window; the small triangle close to style can show you the System CSS (default rules)
- [**Pixel Perfect**](https://getfirebug.com/index.html#Pixel_Perfect) is a Firebug add-on that overlays a PNG over your page, for comparison and alignment purposes.
  Don't go the *pixel-freak* route if your HTML/CSS work is 1px off your design though :)
- **[Firediff](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13179/) is also a Firebug add-on that tracks changes done in Firebug.** It logs everything you'll do in the HTML pane (great) but also your brief use of the WDT (not so great), say Shift-Ctrl-F to obtain a font-size information in px.
  This is the tool that is the closest to what you ask, though I don't think it's the most valuable one. Well YMMV :)

[image: Firediff snapshot of its Firebug tracking]

- *Thou should use **multiple monitors*** as does [St Jeff](https://blog.codinghorror.com/multiple-monitors-and-productivity/).
  This is especially useful as I'm always transforming sth in sth else: looking at PSD/PNG in Adobe software and writing HTML code in an editor, writing CSS rules in the editor and checking in the browser, auditing accessibility of a website in the browser and writing down the results in OOo Writer, etc
- *`Reload page`* (in browser along with saving file in the text editor and switching windows) can take ONE keypress: I replaced Ctrl-S / Alt-Tab to browser / F5 by an **AutoHotKey** macro a long time ago (code below) and bound it to a strategically placed yet useless key on my french keyboard: the `²` key that sits between Tab and Esc.
  Saved me from tendonitis and/or carpal tunnel syndrome!
  I use deadkeys and ² to do the same with IE6, IE7 and Safari.

  ---

  #NoEnv  ; 4 lines to begin an AHK script
  SendMode Input
  SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
  SetTitleMatchMode RegEx

  #IfWinActive, Notepad
  ²::
  Send ^s
  IfWinExist, Mozilla Firefox
  WinActivate, Mozilla Firefox
  Send ^r   ; refresh the browser
  IfWinNotActive, Notepad
  return

  ---

So here are Firediff and my other productivity tools

Answer (score 2):

A trick I use is...

Do the html/css on your regular text editor on one monitor, and use `setTimeout(function(){ location.reload() }, 30000 );` to automatically refresh your browser in the other.

If you're on linux you can probably setup a script to watch whenever you "save" file(s) in your css directory so when they are actually saved, bind it to the browser and refresh the tab , though I haven't really done that yet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the [Firefox extension "Browser Turns Editor"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/182865/) is quite what you're looking for, but it might be. I guess you would have to edit the page in design mode and then inspect parts of it in Firebug, to see what the corresponding HTML is. Or something like that.