# any good new web-developer browser addons? (as in released in the last 6 months)

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser, google-chrome

I used to be pretty ontop of the latest plugins but it's lost my attention recently (probably due to so many itentical blog articles called `'the best {num here} addons for firefox'`).

Last time i looked i found:

`firequery` and `firepicker` which are now indespensible,

so what's new?

any hot new extensions that have found their way into your daily work?

Comment: +1 I've never heard of firequery before, looks useful. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Pendule](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gbkffbkamcejhkcaocmkdeiiccpmjfdi)  Is a pretty good all around developer tool for Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

The first one from a [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272620/any-tool-to-allow-moving-of-elements-on-a-webpage-to-aid-design/3273088#3273088), design-oriented:

- [**Firediff**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13179/) is a Firebug add-on that tracks changes done in Firebug. It logs everything you'll do in the HTML pane (great) but also your brief use of the WDT (not so great), say Shift-Ctrl-F to obtain a font-size information in px.

[image: Firediff snapshot of its Firebug tracking]

- Firebug, accessibilty and help to keyboard implementations: [Firefocus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/49662/) will track the element that currently has focus
- [**QuickJava**](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/1237/) allow to *easily turn on or off Java, Javascript, Flash, Silverlight and Automatic loading of images from the Statusbar and/or the Toolbar without having to open the Options or Plugins dialog!*
  Must have!
- **Performance related**: the HTTP Archive (HAR) format is being adopted by [numerous tools](https://web.archive.org/web/20130514141919/http://groups.google.com/group/http-archive-specification/web/har-adopters?hl=en). This format allows you to compare a website performance day after day or 1 year later and brings interoperability.

Comment: havent seen firediff before - nice one!

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome has a [page of featured developer extensions](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/featured/web_dev). And since the Google Chrome extension system is pretty new, all these extensions are pretty new.

I personally use a few of them on a regular basis. Besides the good ones already mentioned, I’d say [Speed Tracer](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ognampngfcbddbfemdapefohjiobgbdl) is extremely handy.

Comment: yep, speed tracer's great (again not that new though), i'm literally considerring the last 6 months... if you like speed tracer be sure to check out dynatrace ajax edition (its more powerful for deep tracing js performance)

Comment: Ah, you got me — Speed Tracer came out seven months ago. ;-)

The dynaTrace tool looks very neat.

Answer (score 0):

Not new, but one that I use nearly constantly and few others I tell about it seem to know of:  Web Developer 1.18 (http://chrispederick.com/)  Originally, I found myself using it most for highlighting divs quickly and easily.  Later, on one particularly difficult job I realized that I can use it to reliably toggle CSS, Javascript, etc with a simple checkbox.  Also, a tool called "view generated source" has allowed me to easily identify issues that popup in IE and Safari that firefox is intelligent enough to know about and fix on its own (what a concept, Microsoft)  Used in conjunction with Firebug, there's almost no UI issue I can think of that should stop you.